# Pass data with segue Model View Presenter

Tags: ios, swift

I have three view controllers: HomeVC and HomeDetailsVC. The problem is that I want to pass data from HomeVC to HomeDetailsVC and later to ThirdVC with segues.

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

var homeData: [WorkoutModelInfo]= []

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
     if segue.identifier == "WorkoutDetailsViewController" {
            if let homeDetailVC = segue.destination as? HomeDetailsVC {
                guard let selectedIndex = sender as? Int else { return }
                let titleInSender = homeData[selectedIndex].workoutName
                homeDetailVC.presenter.convertData(homeData: home[selectedIndex])
            }
}

class HomeDetailsPresenter: class {
   var titleValue: String = ""
   var workoutDetailsData = [HomeDetailsData]()
   var dateOfWorkout: String = ""


 func convertData(workoutModel: WorkoutModelInfo) {
        
        var exercises = [ExerciseCellInNewWorkout]()
        for row in 0..<workoutModel.exercises.count {
            exercises.append(ExerciseCellInNewWorkout(opened: false, workoutModel: 
 workoutModel.exercises[row]))
        }
        
        workoutDetailsData = exercises
        titleValue = workoutModel.workoutName
        dateOfWorkout = workoutModel.workoutDate

}

class HomeDetailsVC: UIViewController {

 lazy var presenter = HomeDetailsPresenter(homeDetailsPresenterDelegate: self)
.
.
.
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ThirdVC {
         destinationVC.workoutNameText = presenter.titleValue
         destinationVC.workoutDateText = presenter.dateOfWorkout
         destinationVC.data = presenter.workoutDetailsData
 }
}
```

}

I have two questions to this issue:

1. Is correct to calling vc presenter (like in first class when I call homeDetailVC.presenter.convertData(homeData: home[selectedIndex])) during segue?
2. Using MVP pattern is correct to take values directly from presenter when prepare segue (like in homeDetailsVC in preparing segue "destinationVC.workoutNameText = presenter.titleValue")? Or maybe better approach is create variables directly in view controller and update them from presenter with delegates?

Comment: delegates could work here, but you would need to keep in mind that they are one to one. So if you passed data from VC1 to VC2, you would need one delegate to handle this. You would then need a second delegate to pass from VC2 to VC3. You could potentially use the notification/observer pattern to pass that data to all views at the same time.

Comment: Ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Is correct to calling vc presenter (like in first class when I call `homeDetailVC.presenter.convertData(homeData: home[selectedIndex]))` during segue?

I would generally avoid having a view controller reach in and call some method of some property (i.e., the presenter) of another view controller. You are tightly coupling/entangling each source view controller with implementation details of its destination view controller(s). E.g., you are requiring that the home view controller knows that the details view controller has a presenter, and that this presenter has a `convertData` method, etc.

That is not good. You want to keep all of these various classes as loosely coupled as possible. All you care about is whether the destination view controller can receive some data.

Here is one example implementation. E.g., I might suggest a protocol to indicate whether the destination can receive some particular model object(s), e.g.,

```swift
protocol WorkoutDetailsReceiver {                   // is some destination capable of receiving `Workout` information
    func receive(_ value: Workout)
}
```

Then the presenter for the destination view controller would conform to this, updating its model with the supplied value:

```swift
extension HomeDetailsPresenter: WorkoutDetailsReceiver {
    func receive(_ value: Workout) {
        workout = value                             // e.g. save the data that was passed to this presenter

        // And if you want to do some conversion/processing of the data, do that here,
        // but the caller should not be involved in those sorts of details.
    }
}
```

But rather than having the source view controller from reaching into the destination view controller and invoke some method in its presenter, I personally use the same protocol, with a simple implementation that passes it along to its presenter:

```swift
extension HomeDetailsVC: WorkoutDetailsReceiver {
    func receive(_ value: Workout) {
        presenter.receive(value)
    }
}
```

Having set up this pattern for receiving data, now the home view controller only needs to see if the destination can receive the `Workout` information:

```swift
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var presenter = HomePresenter(delegate: self)

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let receiver = segue.destination as? WorkoutDetailsReceiver {
            presenter.supplyWorkout(to: receiver)
        }
    }
}
```

Note, because we have a MVP app, the `HomeViewController` does not hold any model data. Its own presenter has that. So we have some method for the source view controller to pass along the necessary data to the destination.

E.g.,

```swift
class HomePresenter {
    private weak var delegate: HomePresenterDelegate?
    private var workouts: [Workout] = []
    private var selectedIndex: Int?

    init(delegate: HomePresenterDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    // just as an example

    func supplyWorkout(to receiver: WorkoutDetailsReceiver) {
        guard let selectedIndex = selectedIndex else {
            return
        }

        receiver.receive(workouts[selectedIndex])
    }

    ...
}
```

Anyway, the end result is that the home view controller only needs to know whether the destination (the details view controller) can receive the information that you want to pass.

> 2. Using MVP pattern is correct to take values directly from presenter when prepare segue (like in `homeDetailsVC` in preparing segue `destinationVC.workoutNameText = presenter.titleValue`)? Or maybe better approach is create variables directly in view controller and update them from presenter with delegates?

I once tried this “individual properties” approach: It works, but I found it to be brittle. As the app evolves, you want to change what data the destination wants, and if you have individual variables, it is too easy to forget about some property that needs to be passed along. Also, as you start injecting lots of properties from one scene to another, you end up littering the view controller with a lot of those staging properties (whether stored or computed) that really belong in its presenter. By having a protocol, you have a simple, consistent contract between the source and destination about what data the destination expects.

Now, all of that having been said, do not get too lost in the above details. There are lots of variations on the theme. But the governing principle is that we should keep our objects loosely coupled.